# Minecraft | Help with Scoreboards and Tags

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

For a map, I am trying to make a blaze rod named "Fire Rod" that gives the player fire resistance, but only when they hold it. To get this item, a player would have to stand anywhere on a 3x3 area with an armor stand in the middle named "testFR". The player has to stand there for 10 seconds to get it. If they step away, their wait time gets reset. Basically, the player has to stand on the area for 10 seconds straight. The item itself will also get /clear ed from the player after holding it for 10 seconds total.

I've already tried and made it work. The only issue is that it only works fine in singleplayer. In multiplayer, I'm encountering serious issues that are most likely based around @a selectors because when something happens involving the Fire Rod, both players get affected by the tags and this and that. Also, there's an issue that all the players online have to be standing ni the area to get the item, etc. My shot at making this is in this schematic for MCEdit, which you can download through this link so you can see what I'm trying to do better or help improve:
https://www.mediafire.com/?6q3ebotvpg456n6

If anyone can help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have not downloaded the schematic but I think I get what you're asking. There's nothing wrong with your scoreboards I think but here's my answer: Search all your command blocks for `@a`. If you find it, try replacing it with `@p`. It's not that simple though... With the command that gives you the item when you are near the armor stand, try

```
execute @e[type=armor_stand,name=NAME] ~ ~ ~ give @p[r=3] FIREROD.
```

I'm not sure if this is specific enough, i dont have Mc edit so if this didn't help, I could make the edits for you if you provide a world download. Hope that helps!

Comment: Here's the world download: https://www.mediafire.com/?uchp65ujjs6r043

Comment: Just in case something went wrong with the scematic I used to transfer the command blocks into a new world, this is the world the thing is actually in. It is an Elytra PvP map. There's a 3x3 area of diorite above where you will spawn in, which is where you stand to get the fire rod. https://www.mediafire.com/?b69b5yei1rfe58c

Comment: I apologize, I could not figure it out! It never gave me the firerod at all. Is there something I missed?